# Is there a function to get Picture size in haskell gloss?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I'm trying to grasp some haskell by drawing simple pictures with gloss library.
Is there a way to get a picture size?

```
circ :: Picture
circ = circle 100
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
width circ -- returns 200
```

Comment: Given the internal representation, it looks hard-ish to do. Gloss essentially uses a representation similar to "draw there two rectangle and this arc, then translate and rotate, then ..." and it's not trivial to compute a bounding box with that. I'd guess there is no such function available in the libraries. Why do you actually need that?

Comment: I'm looking a way to draw 2 pictures beside or above one another.
In fact I'm trying to port functions that I once used in racket: beside and above.

- beside (circle 100) (circle 100) -
- above (circle 100) (circle 100 ) -

would produce a Picture with 2 circles one beside/above the other.